# Transferring a generated property in SOAPUI

Tags: soapui

I'm trying to transfer a property from a one test step to another using a PropertyTransfer.

The property is defined with:

```
name: 'uniqueNo', 
value: '${=new Date().getTime()}'
```

The first test step references the property like so:

```
<ns:lookupRequest>
   <ns:uniqueNumber>${#TestCase#uniqueNo}</ns:uniqueNumber>
</ns:lookupRequest>
```

My source in the transfer step references the `TestCase->uniqueNo` property.

My target in the transfer step is:

```
declare namespace ns="http://www.myCompany";
//ns:lookupRequest/ns:uniqueNumber
```

All I'm succeeding in doing is copying this 'script' into the new test-step, so that the new test step also just *generates* it's own unique number, instead of transferring the *result* of the previous step (what was physically sent in the request in the `<ns:uniqueNumber>` element).

Is there some syntax I'm missing in order to retrieve the result of the expression, as opposed to the expression itself? Or am I going about this the wrong way.

Here's a snapshot of my PropertyTransfer (I've tried various combinations checkboxes to no avail):

[image: PropertyTransfer step]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are correct: what you have done is transfer the *script*, and each time this property is called it will be evaluated again.

If you want to have the script evaluated only once, you need to do it in the test case Setup. Something like this:

```
def timestamp = new Date().getTime()
testCase.setPropertyValue('uniqueNo', timestamp.toString())
```